# Identifying a bottleneck in a multithreaded MQTT publisher

Tags: java, multithreading, mqtt, runnable, executorservice

I'm currently developing a MQTT client service with Eclipse Paho for a bigger software and I'm encountering performance issues. I'm getting a bunch of events that I want to publish to the broker and I'm using GSON for serialization of those events. I've multithreaded the serialization and publishing. According to a rudimentary benchmark serialization and publishing takes up to 1 ms.
I'm using an ExecutorService with a fixed threadpool of size 10 (for now).

My code is currently submitting about 50 Runnables per second to the ExecutorService, but my Broker reports only about 5-10 messages per second.
I've previously benchmarked my MQTT setup and managed to send about 9000+ MQTT messages per second in a non-multithreaded way.

Does the threadpool have that much of an overhead, that I'm only able to get this small amount of publishes out of it?

```
public class MqttService implements IMessagingService{
    protected int PORT = 1883;
    protected String HOST = "localhost";
    protected final String SERVICENAME = "MQTT";
    protected static final String COMMANDTOPIC = "commands";
    protected static final String REMINDSPREFIX = "Reminds/";
    protected static final String VIOLATIONTOPIC = "violations/";
    protected static final String WILDCARDTOPIC = "Reminds/#";
    protected static final String TCPPREFIX = "tcp://";
    protected static final String SSLPREFIX = "ssl://";

    private MqttClient client;
    private MqttConnectOptions optionsPublisher = new MqttConnectOptions();

    private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public MqttService() {
        this("localhost", 1883);
    }

    public MqttService(String host, int port) {
        this.HOST = host;
        this.PORT = port;

    }

    @Override
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.PORT = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.HOST = host;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(AbstractMessage message) {
        pool.submit(new SerializeJob(client,message));
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() {
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(TCPPREFIX + HOST + ":" + PORT, IDPublisher);
            optionsPublisher.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
            client.connect(optionsPublisher);
            client.setCallback(new MessageCallback());
            client.subscribe(WILDCARDTOPIC, 0);
        } catch (MqttException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is the Runnable executed by the ExecutorService. This should not be an issue by itself though, since it only takes up to 1-2 ms to finish.

```
class SerializeJob implements Runnable {
    private AbstractMessage message;
    private MqttClient client;

    public SerializeJob(MqttClient client, AbstractMessage m) {
        this.client = client;
        this.message = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String serializedMessage = MessageSerializer.serializeMessage(message);
        MqttMessage wireMessage = new MqttMessage();
        wireMessage.setQos(message.getQos());
        wireMessage.setPayload(serializedMessage.getBytes());
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            StringBuilder topic = new StringBuilder();
            topic.append(MqttService.REMINDSPREFIX);
            topic.append(MqttService.VIOLATIONTOPIC);
            try {
                client.publish(topic.toString(), wireMessage);
            } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not quite sure what's holing me back. MQTT itself seems to allow for a lot of events, that also can have a big payload, and network cannot possibly an issue either, since I'm currently hosting the broker locally on the same machine as the client.

**Edit with further testing:**

I've synthetically benchmarked now my own setup which consisted of a locally hosted HiveMQ and Mosquitto broker that ran "natively" off the machine. Using the Paho libraries I have sent increasingly bigger messages in batches of 1000. For each batch I calculated the throughput in messages from first to last message. This scenario didn't use any multithreading. With this I've come up with the following performance chart:

[image: Throughput for MQTT messages of different sizes with 2 different brokers]

The machine running both the client and the brokers is a desktop with an i7 6700 and 32 GB of RAM. The brokers had access to all cores and 8 GB of Memory for its VM.

For benchmarking I used the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttPersistenceException;

public class MqttBenchmarker {
    protected static int PORT = 1883;
    protected static String HOST = "localhost";
    protected final String SERVICENAME = "MQTT";
    protected static final String COMMANDTOPIC = "commands";
    protected static final String REMINDSPREFIX = "Reminds/";
    protected static final String VIOLATIONTOPIC = "violations/";
    protected static final String WILDCARDTOPIC = "Reminds/#";
    protected static final String TCPPREFIX = "tcp://";
    protected static final String SSLPREFIX = "ssl://";

    private static MqttClient client;
    private static MqttConnectOptions optionsPublisher = new MqttConnectOptions();
    private static String IDPublisher = MqttClient.generateClientId();

    private static int messageReceived = 0;
    private static long timesent = 0;
    private static int count = 2;
    private static StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    private static StringBuilder in = new StringBuilder();
    private static final int runs = 1000;
    private static boolean receivefinished = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
        Thread sendThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random rd = new Random();
                for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i += i) {
                    byte[] arr = new byte[i];
                    // System.out.println("Starting test run for byte Array of size:
                    // "+arr.length);
                    long startt = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Test for size: " + i + " started.");
                    for (int a = 0; a <= runs; a++) {

                        rd.nextBytes(arr);
                        try {
                            client.publish(REMINDSPREFIX, arr, 1, false);
                        } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (MqttException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        while (!receivefinished) {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                        receivefinished = false;
                        System.out.println("Test for size: " + i + " finished.");
                        out.append("Sending Payload size: " + arr.length + " achieved "
                                + runs / ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startt) / 1000d) + " messages per second.\n");

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(out.toString());
                System.out.println(in.toString());
            }

        });
        sendThread.start();

    }

    private static class MessageCallback implements MqttCallback {

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage arg1) throws Exception {
            if (messageReceived == 0) {
                timesent = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            messageReceived++;
            if (messageReceived >= runs) {
                receivefinished = true;
                in.append("Receiving payload size " + count + " achieved "
                        + runs / ((System.currentTimeMillis() - timesent) / 1000d) + " messages per second.\n");
                count += count;
                messageReceived = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public static void connect() {
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(TCPPREFIX + HOST + ":" + PORT, IDPublisher);
            optionsPublisher.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
            optionsPublisher.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
            optionsPublisher.setCleanSession(false);
            optionsPublisher.setMaxInflight(65535);
            client.connect(optionsPublisher);
            while (!client.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            client.setCallback(new MessageCallback());
            client.subscribe(WILDCARDTOPIC, 0);
        } catch (MqttException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

What's weird is, that the serialized messages that I want to send from my application only use about 4000 bytes. So the theoretical throughput should be around 200 messages per second. Could this still be a problem caused by longer computations inside the callback function? I've already achieved far better results with the mosquitto broker, and I will further test, how far I can push performance with it.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What is MessageSerializer?

Comment: @PavelZdenek it's a class that features a static method that can serialize AbstractMessage via GSON. I included the serialize call in my benchmark though, and its cpu time is included in the 1-2 ms that the SerializeJob takes to finish

Comment: So have you tried without ExecutorService? Set threads to 1, or use just 1 manually created worker thread, or even try doing without threads at all? I believe that Paho have its own loop. I am somewhat suspicious about your use case. MQTT is not designed for large amount of concurrent in-flight messages. Also, do you have the same QoS level in your benchmark and this execution?

Comment: @PavelZdenek I was wondering if maybe the broker (hiveMQ) I was using, had bottleneck issues, because it was running off of a docker container. I installed a native hiveMQ broker, but the problem was still there. So I switched over to a mosquitto broker. I also didn't rely on the broker throughput information anymore, but implemented my own measurements. Those seem to be fine now. I'm not quite sure what the problem was, maybe that I also printed out all serialized messages could have caused an issue.

Comment: With the new Mosquitto broker I've now also found, that i can send about 270 messages per second on QoS 1 and about 12500 messages on Qos 0. I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was exactly. Might have been, that my Callback took to long, since I was printing out all messages. Maybe hivemq has some restrictions on its free broker, or mosquitto is just plain better suited for my use case.

Comment: Once I switched back from dummy messages to real actual messages for testing though the issue returned. It's probably also related to the much bigger payload of my actual messages. I'm continuing testing with different code inside the callback. Calling ```client.publish()``` without multithreading also does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I really have an increasing doubt that MQTT is the right transport for your use case. You have apparently big-ish messages, you have a lot of them, and proof of delivery is essential to you. MQTT can satisfy one requirement, but not all of them. It has other design goals. Is it your authority to use or propose a real message queue instead (AMQP or other) ?

Comment: I'm currently synthetically benchmarking throughput for various message sizes for my setup, to verify it's the message sizes fault. The queue should usually not be used for traffic that high, but send messages from time to time. Since our solution is very generic though, and can be used in many scenarios we don't want to restrict users from the get go. We have a (proprietary) other message queue implemented, but also want to maintain MQTT to possibly release the software open source in the future without removing the feature.

Comment: Also consider designing your application layer around the premise of QoS=0. MQTT was born as transport for redundant data and it really shines when your app can handle occasional gaps and eventual consistency. Mind that QoS>0 is not a proof of delivery to the target consumer but only to the nearest broker, and still the performance penalty is jaw-dropping - as you found out already.

Comment: unfortunately proof of delivery is essential to us, for at least a subset of messages, if not all. So you'd suggest switching to another solution? Could ActiveMQ be a good choice, since it's supporting multiple protocols, including AMQP?

Comment: @PavelZdenek I have now added a bit more data to my question, and according to my benchmark, my application should theoretically be able to achieve 10 times the throughput, even with QoS set to 1. I'm still wondering if my callback function is causing a holdup for receiving messages. This will be what I'll test next.

Comment: I read that [MqttClient](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.html) is a blocking implementation and things may improve by using [MqttAsyncClient](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttAsyncClient.html) instead. But you really need a durable, persistent message queue (yes like AMQP, be it RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ or whatever). MQTT durability is only eventual, the advantage is little memory, little cpu, little overhead. None of that is useful for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem is in the test setup of the MQTT client.

You are using just one single MQTT client. What you are effectively testing is the size of the MQTT inflight window with this formula:

```
  throughput <= inflight window-size / round-trip time
```

HiveMQ has by default a property enabled that is called [`<cluster-overload-protection>`](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/4.2/hivemq/overload-protection.html) that limits the `inflight window` of a single client.

Additionally the paho client is not really suited for high throughput work in a multi threaded context. A better implementation for high performance scenarios would be the [HiveMQ MQTT Client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client).

With 20 clients connected (10 Publishing and 10 receiving), I reach a sustained throughput of around 6000 qos=1 10kb messages per second.

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I work as a software developer for HiveMQ.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was suspecting it being a problem with a default setting of a property. I suspect this is on the broker side of things, and is not affected by passing `setMaxInflight()` a higher value when connecting with the client?

Comment: Sadly, you are correct. The `setMaxInflight()` only limits the client side window size, which the broker must not exceed. The broker can still use a smaller window.
I would really suggest that you use a multitude of clients or tweak the broker parameters.

Comment: By the way, if you like support setting up a production grade HiveMQ or a PoC feel free to contact us: https://www.hivemq.com/contact/.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not exactly sure what the issue was, but switching my broker from HiveMQ to Mosquitto seems to have fixed the issue. Maybe Mosquitto has a different set of default setting compared to HiveMQ, or maybe the free trial version of HiveMQ is limited in some other way than just the number of connected clients.

In any way, Mosquitto worked much better for me, and handled all the messages I could throw at it from my application.